# how to update an array in mongo DB but the index is stored in a variable

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model, mongodb-query

[Example of my database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuXRU.png)

so i want to do a statement like

await Matches.update({seasonID : id}, {$set : {seasonMatches[req.body.index].teamOne.score : 10})

but i cant pass a variable like req.body.index in to the statement

Comment: Can you add your example code? Not only result.

Comment: pass to the statement where? Where is that variable coming from? Are you using code to run queries against mongo? Are you using the mongo shell?

Comment: i am using code yes in Node.js